# I can't insert data to SQLite and can't see my table

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I can't insert data to SQLite and can't see my table.
I try to see the table in DB Browser for SQLite, but I can't see anything inserted and also can't see the rows I created.

here insert method from DataBaseHelper:

```
//Adding new trainee
public void addTrainee(Trainee trainee) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    int count = getShopsCount();

    values.put(COL_ID, 1);
    values.put(COL_USERNAME, trainee.getUsername());
    values.put(COL_NAME, trainee.getName());
    values.put(COL_PASS, trainee.getPassword());
    values.put(COL_EMAIL, trainee.getEmail());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();// Closing database connection
}

// Getting shops Count
public int getShopsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();
    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

here insert registration from main activity:

```
public void confirminput(View v) {
    //If one of the validate retuen false the validation faild.
    if (  !validateEmail() || !validateUsername() || !validateName() || !validatePassword()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Validation NOT OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    //Inserting Trainee.
    Trainee trainee = new Trainee();
    trainee.setUsername(textInputUsername.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    trainee.setName(textInputName.getEditText().getText().toString().trim());
    trainee.setEmail(textInputEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim());
    trainee.setPassword(textInputPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    //Insert Method data .
    myDb.addTrainee(trainee);


}
```

onCreate():

```
//onCreat
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + "("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
            + COL_NAME  + " TEXT," + COL_PASS + " TEXT," +COL_EMAIL + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    this.db = db;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that it's better readable by others? This would be nice.

Comment: please check is there is any error in logcat

Comment: no error ,I really don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Try deleting the App's data or uninstalling the App and then rerunning. It may then work. The database file is only **4k**, this indicates that there are no tables (at least tables that you have defined). My guess is that you've run the App, had an issue in the `onCreate` method (trying to create the table). Corrected the issue and then run the App. The `onCreate` method would then not run as the database then exists. i.e. the `onCreate` method only runs once for the lifetime of the database (deleting the App's data will delete the database).

Comment: P.S. you may wish to delete the line `values.put(COL_ID, 1);`. This would allow you to add just 1 row as subsequent rows would be skipped as the COL_ID column has to be UNIQUE. Not specifying a value (deleting the line) will allow SQLite to assign a unique id (first row would be 1, 2nd likely 2, 3rd likely 3 .........). More info re this here [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: Sorry folks I've tried everything and it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to copy all 3 sqlite files from your device to your desktop before you can browse your SQLite database otherwise it will show empty tables.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping 
problem was creating the wrong table

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String createTraineeTable = "create table trainee ("+COL_ID+" integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT  ," +
            COL_USERNAME+" text not null, "+COL_NAME+" text not null, "+COL_PASS+" text not null,"+COL_EMAIL+" text not null );";

    db.execSQL(createTraineeTable);
    this.db = db;
}
```